Syn Flood Attack
this week I'm facing a problem with my web server. I think we are receiving a Syn flood/DDoS attack. But I don't know how to end it.
So first I think I'm under attack because in top command I have a heavy use from php7.4-fpm.service in different services like web4 and web14. Using netstat -ano | grep :443 | sort I get a lot of connections with LAST_ACK, SYN_REC, and others from different IPs.
$ top
    PID USUARIO   PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM    TEMPO+ COMANDO                                                                        
 759641 web18     20   0  396596 205824 109540 R  21,1   2,5   2:40.11 php-fpm7.4                                                                     
 759787 web4      20   0  450736 257260 108088 R  21,1   3,2   3:23.28 php-fpm7.4                                                                     
 759684 web18     20   0  394532 203776 109540 R  20,8   2,5   2:35.94 php-fpm7.4                                                                     
 760606 web18     20   0  394532 203772 109536 R  20,8   2,5   1:01.23 php-fpm7.4                                                                     
 761776 web4      20   0  341148 220732 106252 R  20,8   2,7   0:06.14 php-fpm7.4                                                                     
 761799 web4      20   0  339908 218876 105684 R  20,8   2,7   0:01.62 php-fpm7.4                                                                     
 760391 web4      20   0  451628 260020 108596 R  20,5   3,2   2:14.83 php-fpm7.4                                                                     
 760549 web18     20   0  396580 205816 109532 R  20,5   2,5   1:10.79 php-fpm7.4                                                                     
 761664 web4      20   0  365724 245468 106260 R  20,5   3,0   0:09.73 php-fpm7.4                                                                     
 760122 web4      20   0  450584 258352 107964 R  20,1   3,2   2:42.37 php-fpm7.4                                                                     
 760389 web4      20   0  450944 257820 108420 R  20,1   3,2   2:14.58 php-fpm7.4  
[...]

My SYN cookie is on, but I still have a lot of connections. I set my php7.4 confs to:
$ nano /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/web4.conf
[...]
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 10
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s;
pm.max_requests = 100
[...]

Using php status I have 300k of requests.
$ systemctl status php7.4-fpm.service 
● php7.4-fpm.service - The PHP 7.4 FastCGI Process Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php7.4-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-12-04 16:22:58 -03; 1 day 20h ago
       Docs: man:php-fpm7.4(8)
    Process: 253627 ExecStartPost=/usr/lib/php/php-fpm-socket-helper install /run/php/php-fpm.sock /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf 74 (code=exited, >
   Main PID: 253623 (php-fpm7.4)
     Status: "Processes active: 18, idle: 7, Requests: 311986, slow: 0, Traffic: 2.1req/sec"
      Tasks: 26 (limit: 9508)
     Memory: 3.1G
        CPU: 1w 3h 17min 18.062s
     CGroup: /system.slice/php7.4-fpm.service
             ├─253623 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
             ├─746242 php-fpm: pool www
             ├─746824 php-fpm: pool www
             ├─746853 php-fpm: pool www
             ├─760260 php-fpm: pool web18
             ├─760389 php-fpm: pool web4
             ├─760391 php-fpm: pool web4
             ├─760470 php-fpm: pool web18
             ├─760476 php-fpm: pool web18
[...]

I tried to block some IPs with UFW they got blocked but soon came another IP to replace it.
I don't know how I can stop the requests or just make them use less CPU. I restart the apache and php service sometimes but the requests keep going.
I was thinking of putting UFW in the Fail2Ban table but Idk if it will work, because looking in ufw.log I see my IP with a lot of UFW DENY, so I think if I use this rule I'll get banned too.
I'm using Linux 5.10.0-17-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.136-1 Apache/2.4.54
[EDIT]
I was looking at my configs and the Syn_cookies was not enabled. So I turned it on in /etc/sysctl.conf and then in my messages log I got the message:
Dec  9 10:49:28 MyPC kernel: [483659.951134] TCP: request_sock_TCP: Possible SYN flooding on port 443. Sending cookies.  Check SNMP counters.

Until Apache receives the HTTP request, it's not going to wake up PHP. If you're seeing an impact on your PHP processes, then this is not a syn flood. More likely that all the Apache slots are used up and you are seeing backed up connections.

I was thinking of putting UFW in the Fail2Ban table

Not quite sure what you are saying here. If your firewall is logging that it is blocking connections, what do you gain by using fail2ban to block the connection which are already being blocked?
If you can profile the attack either from the logs alone or from PHP code injected in your pages, then it does make a lot of sense to use this data as a feed for fail2ban.

Right, how do I know I'm having some PHP code getting injected? I thought it was Syn flood because, looking at the netstat report I have a lot of connections going on.

Code injection? You are jumping from one attack to the next with no evidence of anything. I said YOU SHOULD INJECT CODE to detect the attack and to signal this to Fail2ban.

Oh sorry, I misunderstood. Anyway, I think fail2ban should not be the right thing to use. In his log, I have some UFW blocks, but these IPs still send packages and see the web page.

Fail2ban can spot and block an attack in under 5milliseconds. How long does it take you to respond? If you are still seeing bad requests after you think you have blocked the request using ufw, then maybe there is something wrong with how you are using ufw.

my server has log like that "... TCP: request_sock_TCP: Possible SYN flooding on port 443. ..."
and solved with this simple iptables rule

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 --tcp-flags
FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m connlimit --connlimit-above 30 --connlimit-mask
32 --connlimit-saddr -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable


iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK
SYN -m connlimit --connlimit-above 30 --connlimit-mask 32
--connlimit-saddr -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

*becareful to adjust the limit value (--connlimit-above )
